# how to configure nppcrypt plugin parameters on notepad++

Tags: encryption, notepad++, aes

I'm using several online encryption tools to convert plain text with AES (such as `https://www.javainuse.com/aesgenerator`).
These are the required parameters:

```
AES 128 bit - mode ECB - output Base64
```

With imput "*sample_text*" and key "*my_secret_key123*" the result is: *240WkpG6ltUFolBLg+EZtw==*

How can I obtain the same result using the nppcrypt plugin?
On the **basic** tab I've selected:

```
chyper: E-R Rijndael
key-lenght: 128 Bits
mode: ecb
password: my_secret_key123
```

On **encoding** tab:

```
base64 is checked
```

On **key** tab I don't know exactly the parameter to use

On **iv** tab option is disabled

On **auth** tab add hmac is disabled

Comment: _nppcrypt_ expects a password from which the _actual_ key is derived with a key derivation function (that is selected and configured in the _key_ tab), while on the web site the key is entered _directly_. I.e. _nppcrypt_ cannot be configured to reproduce the result of the web site. This would require the password to be derived from the key, which is not possible because key derivation functions are not reversible.

Comment: It is a shame the key derivation function cannot be excluded living the user free to choose whether directly type the password or not.
Maybe I can hope in a future release...